# About HERE ios SDK, License Key, App ID, or App Code not set. (NMAKit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

I just followed the instruction from HERE **iOS SDK**, However, the console says, "`NMAKit FATAL`: License Key, App ID, or App Code not set.
"
I did set up the authorization method in `AppDelegte`, It still doesn't work.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [NMAApplicationContext setAppId:kHelloMapAppID appCode:kHelloMapAppCode licenseKey:kHelloMapLicenseKey];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved. The reason why I can't receive the signal, coz the identifier name is not matched with my license key. Once I changed it, it works properly now.